# Obtain List of Roles in EF Core 3.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I would like to obtain a list of all identity roles in EF core without the use of UserManager/RoleManager. I am using EF Core 3.1

Currently in my startup:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
                .AddRoles<ApplicationRole>()
                .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<ApplicationRole>>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders(); //2FA
```

Then in my Context:

```
public partial class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
        {

        }

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }
        //....
    }
```

My ApplicationUser and ApplicationRole are defined as the following:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
    }

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<String>
    {
        public int Hierarchy { get; set; }

        public ApplicationRole() : base()
        {

        }

        public ApplicationRole(string roleName) : base(roleName)
        {

        }
    }
```

Then I simply try calling in any controller I would like to access (_context is the ApplicationDBContext):

```
var list = _context.Roles.ToArray();
```

In which I get the error:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name 'ApplicationUserId'.'
```

The ultimate goals is to add an ICollection of ApplicationRole to the ApplicationUser context since EF Core does not seem to support it. I am even unable to do a LINQ2Query join from UserRoles to Role.

Any help is appreciated as I've spent many hours on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright I finally figured it out, in case anyone is wondering. It is not able to properly map the roles because the ApplicationDBContext is inheriting the wrong configuration of IdentityDbContext model. For this you must create your own class that inherits IdentityUserRole and implement the proper IdentityDBContext.

```
public partial class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, IdentityUserClaim<string>, ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<string>, IdentityRoleClaim<string>, IdentityUserToken<string>>
```

Where ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole and ApplicationUserRole are your custom classes.

```
public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    public ApplicationUserRole() : base()
    {

    }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
}
```

For some reason EF was trying to generate additional columns of "`UserId1`" and "`RoleId1`", to avoid this I simply instructed the model to take the inheritance of IdentityUserRole, make sure your Id properties match the TKey type.

Then I was able to properly evaluate the roles. Then to get the mapping I added the following to `ApplicationUser` and `ApplicationRole` classes:

```
public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
```

Now to map the new entities I added the following to the modelBuilder:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasOne(e => e.Role)
            .WithMany(e => e.UserRoles)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.RoleId);

            entity.HasOne(e => e.User)
            .WithMany(e => e.UserRoles)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId);
        });
```

Simple as that, don't include any configuration whatsoever to ApplicationUser or ApplicationRole as IdentityDBContext will handle that properly.

Now you can chain include/join to get the actual `ApplicationRole` class instead of `IdentityRole<TKey>`

eg:

```
var list = _context.Users.Include(u => u.UserRoles).ThenInclude(ur => ur.Role).ToList();
```

---

To Summarize:

1. Specify the proper instance of IdentityDBContext
2. Create the junction table entity of ApplicationUserRole
3. Setup virtual properties to map ApplicationUser and ApplicationRole
4. Setup <strike>virtual properties</strike> to map RoleId and UserId matching TKey
5. Create entity mapping with the modelbuilder but leave the ApplicationUser/ApplicationRole entities alone